# Mysql - full text search - match value in where?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, where-clause

I have query like this

```
SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+iron +maiden') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+iron +maiden') ORDER BY m DESC;
```

Works perfectly fine, results are sorted, everythings good.
Then I tried to limit my results to some best matches. I noticed m is sth between 4 and 20 (not always) so 
i thought:

```
SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+iron +maiden') m FROM mp3 WHERE m > 10 AND MATCH (search) AGAINST ('+iron +maiden') ORDER BY m DESC;
```

Bam! *ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'm' in 'where clause'*

Now I know it's not going to work, but I don't know why, maybe I'm tired or something...
So I'd like to ask you:

1. Why it didn't work?
2. Is there similar working solution? (sql only, I know i can filter results later)

Cheers

**EDIT**
So as @alko suggested I did some benchmarking and it looks promising:

```
Match against within inner select (without WHERE m > 10 so resultset is identical as in match against below):
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+metallica') m    FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+metallica')) matched_mp3 ORDER BY m DESC;
2818 rows in set (0.03 sec)
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+dead +weather') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+dead +weather')) matched_mp3 ORDER BY m DESC;
6968 rows in set (0.10 sec)
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+led +zeppelin') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+led +zeppelin')) matched_mp3 ORDER BY m DESC;
1381 rows in set (0.02 sec)
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+lana +del +ray +paradise') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+lana +del +ray +paradise')) matched_mp3 ORDER BY m DESC;
7447 rows in set (0.11 sec)

Match against:
SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+metallica') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+metallica') ORDER BY m DESC;
2818 rows in set (0.03 sec)
SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+dead +weather') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+dead +weather') ORDER BY m DESC;
6968 rows in set (0.10 sec)
SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+led +zeppelin') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+led +zeppelin') ORDER BY m DESC;
1381 rows in set (0.01 sec)
SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+lana +del +ray +paradise') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+lana +del +ray +paradise') ORDER BY m DESC;
7447 rows in set (0.12 sec)

Match against within inner select (with WHERE m > 10)
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+metallica') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+metallica')) matched_mp3 WHERE m > 10 ORDER BY m DESC;
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+dead +weather') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+dead +weather')) matched_mp3 WHERE m > 10 ORDER BY m DESC;
46 rows in set (0.08 sec)
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+led +zeppelin') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+led +zeppelin')) matched_mp3 WHERE m > 10 ORDER BY m DESC;
1070 rows in set (0.01 sec)
SELECT id, search, m FROM (SELECT id, search, MATCH(search) AGAINST('+lana +del +ray +paradise') m FROM mp3 WHERE MATCH(search) AGAINST('+lana +del +ray +paradise')) matched_mp3 WHERE m > 10 ORDER BY m DESC;
532 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work independently from full text search, as for example

```
select concat(name, ' ', surname) as full_name
  from user
 where full_name = 'john smith'
```

will end up with the same error. The reason is that `select` is evaluated prior to the `where` clause. Hence, when `where` clause is evaluated no aliased expressions exist yet. Probably the easiest way is to wrap with inner select:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT id, 
                search, 
                MATCH(search) AGAINST('+iron +maiden') m 
         FROM mp3) matched_mp3
  WHERE m > 10 
  ORDER BY m DESC;
```

Comment: Ok, that's quite simple solution. I wonder about it's performance. I have about 1200k records... Ok while writing this I noticed my mysql console is open so I did quick test. Normal select(1st from my post) for ('+foo + fighters'): 2222 rows in set (0.06 sec); inner select as above: 262 rows in set (7.98 sec). So it's kinda slow

Comment: @f1ames, first, you should compare sqls returning equal datasets, or it's unfair comparaison. And i forgot `where match (...)` part for the inner query, did you include that? Second, it's a question to analyzer/exec plan. For oracle db I am quite sure sqls will be executed equally. Don't know that much about mysql analyzer.

Comment: Ok, I think main cause was I haven't noticed WHERE in inner select is missing:D Take a look at my post and query times. It shows you are probably right about equal executions of this two type of queries.